# Getting exception from @JsonTest annotation with spring-boot-starter-test 1.4 snapshot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to use the new @JsonTest annotation in spring-boot-starter-test 1.4 and I'm getting a weird error. It seems like the @JsonTest annotation depends on a class that doesn't get added to the classpath. Here's my test...

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@JsonTest
public class JsonSerializationTest {
...
}
```

And here's the error:

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy

at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)
at java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)
at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Class.java:3415)
```

If I remove the @JsonTest annotation I get this error instead, because there's nothing setting up the ApplicationContext:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot load an ApplicationContext with a NULL 'contextLoader'.
```

Anyone know what class @JsonTest is trying to load that spring-boot doesn't include in the dependencies?

Comment: The JVM's diagnostics for `TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy` are really poor. You can figure out the missing type by putting a breakpoint on its constructor

Comment: It appears to be these two classes:

import org.springframework.boot.context.TypeExcludeFilter;
import org.springframework.boot.jackson.JsonComponent;

Answer (score 1):

The two missing classes are new in Spring Boot 1.4 so it looks like you have a mixture of versions on the classpath. You need to update your pom or build.gradle to make sure that the versions are consistent. The easiest way to do this is to remove any version declarations and to allow Spring Boot's dependency management to take care of it for you.

Comment: Thanks. I had updated my dependencies to 1.4 but the parent pom was still pointing at 1.3.5